# Is there any way I can split Location column to Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-maps

```
ALTER TABLE My_table ADD Latitude  VARCHAR(8000)
ALTER TABLE My_table ADD Longitude VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT 
    [Latitude] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), SUBSTRING('[Location 1]', ',', 1)), 
    [Longitude] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), SUBSTRING('[Location 1]', ',', -1))
```

I get this error

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of substring function.

Comment: Why would you store latitude and longitude as strings?

Comment: Please don't tag spam.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thank you for your quick response.I might have putted wrong datatype. I was not sure which data type is suited for Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: Have you tried smaller varchar lengths? aside from 8000?

Comment: @barudo This is one of the sample record I have in my database (39.2346264640, -76.6031273836). yes I have tried with smaller varchar lenghts

Comment: You need different `SUBSTRING` parameters, and the use of the `CHARINDEX()` function. Try: `SELECT [Latitude]=CONVERT(Decimal(16,13), SUBSTRING(Left([Location 1], Len([Location 1])-1), Charindex(',', [Location 1]) + 1, Len([Location 1]))), 
 [Longitude]=CONVERT(Decimal(16,13), SUBSTRING([Location 1], 2, Charindex(',', [Location 1]) - 2)`

Comment: @Abde . . . The appropriate data type is a decimal of some sort, perhaps `decimal(10, 6)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample based on your data elements. It selects out the Latitude and Longitude based on my understanding of what your query was attempting. This works on a variable for testing purposes:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(60)
SET @a = '(39.2346264640, -76.6031273836)'

SELECT [Latitude]=CONVERT(Decimal(16,13), SUBSTRING(Left(@a, Len(@a)-1), Charindex(',', @a) + 1, Len(@a))), 
    [Longitude]=CONVERT(Decimal(16,13), SUBSTRING(@a, 2, Charindex(',', @a) - 2))
```

The output in this case was:

```
Latitude            Longitude
-76.6031273836000   39.2346264640000
```